# Best way to store a class in Google datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to design a database to where I would store objects that are instances of different classes but are extended from one common class. Along with the object, I would store key that will be used to identify the object. The relationship between key-object is N-1 unidirectional(key -> object).

I thought of using Google App Engine's datastore to create two entities(ObjectEntity and KeyEntity).

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class KeyEntity{
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key id;
 @Persistent
 private String keyForObject;
 @Persistent
 private ObjectEntity object;

 //setters and getters
}

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class ObjectEntity{
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key id;
 @Persistent
 private String objectName;
 @Persistent
 private CommonParentClass object;

 //setters and getters
}
```

Is this the right way or is there a better way to store objects?

Comment: if it works use it till you find a problem or a better way.

Comment: I cant understand the point of the KeyEntity, why dont just store a string collection on your ObjectEntity?